# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis MQTT broker refuses connections - possible connection limit

Tags: mqtt, paho, activemq-artemis

I'm running Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 inside VM for a month now and just noticed that after around 90 always connected MQTT clients Artemis broker is not accepting new connections. I need Artemis to support at least 200 MQTT clients.

What could be the reason for that? How can I remove this "limit"? Could the VM resources like low memory be causing this?

After restarting Artemis service, all connection are dropped, and I'm able to connect again.

I was receiving this message in logs:

```
WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ229031: Connection failure to <ip-address> has been detected: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
```

Also this one using Paho library for MQTT client:

```
Connection lost
msg : Connection lost
loc : Connection lost cause : java.io.EOFException
excep : Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
```

I'm attaching `broker.xml` config:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 1.43 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 700000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>700000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      
      <page-sync-timeout>700000</page-sync-timeout>


            <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large mesasge control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->


         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:8883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis has no default connection limit. I just wrote a quick test based on [this](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/36a771150b3ce7a0d889f7df3b7c7a6cd37769f7/tests/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/tests/integration/mqtt/imported/PahoMQTTTest.java#L55) which uses the Paho 1.2.5 MQTT client. It spun up 500 concurrent connections using both normal TCP and WebSockets. The test finished in less than 20 seconds with no errors. I'm just running this test on my laptop.

I noticed that your `journal-buffer-timeout` is `700000` which seems quite high which means you have a very *low* write speed of 1.43 writes per millisecond (i.e. a slow disk). The `journal-buffer-timeout` that is calculated, for example, on my laptop is `4000` which translates into a write-speed of 250 which is *significantly* faster than yours. My laptop is nothing special, but it does have an SSD. That said, SSDs are pretty common. If this low write-speed is indicative of the overall performance of your VM it may simply be too weak to handle the load you want. To be clear, this value isn't related directly to MQTT connections. It's just something I noticed while reviewing your configuration that *may* be indirect evidence of your issue.

The `journal-buffer-timeout` value is calculated and configured automatically when the instance is created. You can re-calculate this value later and configure it manually using the `bin/artemis perf-journal` command.

Ultimately, your issue looks environmental to me. I recommend you inspect your VM and network. TCP dumps may be useful to see perhaps how/why the connection is being reset. Thread dumps from the server during the time of the trouble would also be worth inspecting.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks for the response. OK, I see. VM has 32 GB SSD (ZFS RAID-Z2) and 8 GB RAM. I will add more resources for the VM and check if that helps. Expect a response here soon. When is the `journal-buffer-timeout` calculated? Is it calculated and set automatically when Artemis service is  restarted or once the system is rebooted? If it doesn't change automatically, I'll set it manually.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. Hope that helps!

Comment: Upgraded VM resources but still calculation for `journal-buffer-timeout` is pretty much the same ~700000 or even worse a bit, which is strange because VM is using SSDs. Need some time to see how Artemis will behave, so I would leave this as an open question for some time. I'll be back for sure.

Comment: Have you had a chance to get any TCP or thread dumps? Those are likely going to be more useful at this point.

Comment: It didn't reach that number of 90-100 users, but it seems to work fine. Thanks for help. In case of new issues, I'll collect the dumps.